# Uniqueness solutions of $dx/dt = f^2(x) + e^{-t}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Someone can help me in the following problem? Is a question of [Zhang](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=sc-WpB0vjeYC&lpg=PP1&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA40#v=onepage&q&f=false).

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $dx/dt = f^2(x) + e^{-t}$ has the property of uniqueness of solution.

First, I'm not sure that $f^2(x)$ referred composition or power. I tried both ways and I failed.

My idea was repeated the proof of Cauchy-Picard Theorem showing that

$$ F(x(t)) = x(0) + \int_{0}^{t}\left[ f^2(x(t)) - e^{-t} \right] dt$$

is a contraction.

But I end up getting to the point where it seems I have to use that $f^2(x)$ satisfy a Lipschitz condition. But that does not seem true both in the case of the case of a composition as in case of the square power. For example, consider $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$, we have $f^2(x)$, seen as composition is $\sqrt[4]{|x|}$, which don't satisfy a Lipschitz condition. And consider $f(x) = \sqrt[4]{|x|}$, we have $f^2(x)$, seen as square power, is $\sqrt{|x|}$, which don't satisfy a Lipschitz condition.

---

Some progress:

We have 
$$x'(t) = f^2(x) + e^{-t} \Leftrightarrow x'(t) - e^{-t} = f^2(x)  \Leftrightarrow  (x(t) + e^{-t})'= f^2(x) $$

By the variable change $y(t) = x(t) + e^{-t}$, we have
$$y'(t) = f^2(y(t) - e^{-t}) = g^2(y(t))$$

See that the last step is valid both to composition case as in the power case. So, we have reduced the problem for the uniqueness of the problem

$$ y' = g^2(y), $$

where $g$ is merely a continuous function.

I do not know about you, but I think that this is not true.

I think that $g(y) = \sqrt[4]{y}$, for $y\geq 0$ e $g(y)$, for $y<0$, is a counterexample in the power case.

Comment: it does not play any role if $f^{2}$ means composition or power, both result in a continous function so i think this is w.l.o.g. unimportant :-) what exactly do you use the lipschitz condition for?

Comment: For the Banach fixed-point theorem on $F$. Once $x$ is a solution of the IVP iff is a fixed-point of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that $f^2(x)$ means the square of $f(x)$, I have the following idea. Consider a local solution $x(t)$ of this differential equation on some interval $[a-r,a+r]$, $r>0$, satisfying some initial condition $x(a)=b$. The right hand side of the differential equation is positive and therefore $x$ is a strictly increasing function mapping  $[a-r,a+r]$ to some interval $[c,d]$, say, where $c<b<d$.
Consider its inverse function $z=x^{-1}$ defined on $[c,d]$ which is also differentiable. As $z(x(t))=t$
for all $t$ in $[a,b]$, differentiation gives $z'(x(t))x'(t)=1$. Replacing $t=z(s)$, $s$ in $[c,d]$, gives $z'(s)=1/x'(z(s))$. Now we use the differential equation $x'(t)=f^2(x(t))+e^{-t}$, replace $t=z(s)$ and find that $z$ satisfies the differential equation
$$z'(s)=\frac1{f^2(s)+\exp(-z(s))}$$
and the initial condition $z(b)=a$. The above differential equation satisfies the hypothesis of Picard-Lindelöf's theorem, because the right hand side has a continuous partial derivative with respect to $z$.
Therefore it has a unique solution, not only locally but also globally.
Hence the function $x(t)$ we considered in the beginning must be the
inverse of the unique solution of the $z$-differential equation satisfying $z(b)=a$. This determines $x=x(t)$ uniquely.
To complete this approach, we can show that the solution of the $z$-differential equation (with initial condition) is stricly increasing and has therefore an inverse function.
EDIT: The right hand side of the $z$-differential equation is $F(s,z)=1/(f^2(s)+\exp(-z))$ and continuous on $R^2$ with a continuous partial derivative with respect to $z$. By a theorem based on Picard-Lindelöf, for every initial condition $z(b)=a$, there is a unique solution $z:]c,d[\to R$ having maximal interval of definition ($c,d$ can be infinite, $c<b<d$). Either $c=\infty$ or $\lim_{s\to c} |z(s)|=\infty$ or both.
As $z'(s)$ is positive, $z$ is strictly increasing and hence its image $z(]c,d[)$ is also an open interval, say $]A,B[$. Its inverse function $x:]A,B[\to R$ is then also differentiable and, by a calculation analogous to the above, is a solution of $x'=f^2(x)+e^{-t}$, $x(a)=b$. Actually it is the unique solution having a maximal interval of definition.

Comment: An interesting approach, but I don't understand the following:  "Therefore it has a unique solution ... globally".  Picard-Lindelöf doesn't guarantee that.  Indeed, if $f \equiv 0$ (not excluded) then we have $z'(s) = \exp\,(z(s))$, which has all solutions blowing up to infinity in finite time: $z(s) = -\ln\,(C - s)$, $C \in \mathbb{R}$.  I wonder how that affects the validity of the overall argument.

Comment: "Globally" only means that the solution is not only uniquely determined in a small neighborhood of the initial condition, but also when continued  (as a solution) as far as possible. If a Lipschitz condition holds in the neighborhood of any point, then this follows from Picard-Lindelöf. It then follows that solutions to initial value problems can be continued to solutions with maximal interval of existence. The solution does not have to be defined on the whole real axis for all this. If $f(x)=0$, then your solution gives $x(t)=-e^{-t}+C$.

Comment: If so, that's O.K.